# Create-React-App: .env file doesn't parse correctly

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

My CRA project isn't parsing my environment variables. I see this in the docs:

> By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other
>   environment variables starting with REACT_APP_

And here is some code for testing:

```
// .env in the project root folder
REACT_APP_GOOGLE=google.com
REACT_APP_API_POST_URL=http://localhost:4000/api/

// App.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

  componentDidMount() {
    if (dotenv.error) {
      console.log('dotenv.error', dotenv.error);
    } else { console.log('dotenv.parsed', dotenv.parsed); // undefined
    }
  }


// App.js insider render()
<button
   onClick={e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("process.env", process.env); // 
// {NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: ""}
// NODE_ENV: "development"
// PUBLIC_URL: ""             
console.log("process.env.NODE_ENV", process.env.NODE_ENV); // development               
console.log("process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE", process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE); // undefined
    }}
    >log .env</button>
```

Anyone know why it's not parsing the env variables?

Comment: what version of `react-scripts` do you have installed?

Comment: From package.json: `"react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const googleEnvVariable = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="App">{googleEnvVariable}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is your .env

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE=hereisyourenvvar
```

You should see hereisyourenvvar

EDIT: updated answer to display on the screen instead of the console.log...

Comment: Ok, I did this outside render(): `googleEnvVariable = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE;`
And then inside render(): `<div>{this.googleEnvVariable}</div>`
Nothing displayed. I guess it's still undefined

Comment: @SeanDezoysa I'm not sure I understand... So you have replaced API_KEY with googleVairable so just console.log googleVariable and you will see it in the console...

Comment: There should be no `this` @SeanDezoysa

Comment: Ok, I updated the code (moving the const assignment outside the class). Tried rendering it but it still doesn't appear unfortunately

Comment: @SeanDezoysa If you simply copy paste what I have it will work... we are defining it here: `const googleEnvVariable = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE;` - It's not possible.... I don't know what else you have in there..

Comment: @SeanDezoysa If you are using create-react-app you do not need to install or import detenv... It comes baked in... you simply need to create a `.env` file in the `src` directory... define your variable there as I showed you... assign it to a const in you `App.js` like I showed you and it should work...

Comment: Ok, got it working. I put the .env file in the project root and rebuilt the app. I suspect not rebuilding was causing most of the issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the code you gave, it seems like you forgot to call the `config` function (unless you didn't show it). If you want your `.env` to be implemented, you will have to do the following at the top level of your project :

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
// Load ENV vars
const dotEnvOptions = {
    path: 'env/dev.env' //Example path relative to your project folder
}

dotenv.config(dotEnvOptions)
```

To figure out what is going wrong you may turn on logging to help debug why certain keys or values are not being set as you expect :

```
dotenv.config({ debug: true })
```

From there, if a path/variable isnt recognized, it will be printed int he console :

[image]

If you are not seeing anything, it either means that your path is wrong or that the code isn't executed

Comment: My .env file is in the project root, is there an error in this code? rendering the const shows 'nothing found'

`const dotEnvOptions = {
  path: './.env'
};
dotenv.config(dotEnvOptions);

const googleEnvVariable = process.env.REACT_APP_API_POST_URL || 'nothing found';`

Comment: also tried setting the path as '.env' and '/.env' without success

Comment: Alright, just type `path: '.env'` instead, it should hopefully do the trick.  
Ok, nervermind

Comment: Is the quotation mark in your variable supposed to be here ? : `"http://localhost:4000/api/`

Comment: No! I have removed them. But it still does not pick up the ENV variables

Comment: Alright, could you try adding the debug option to the config to see what's going wrong ?

Comment: Ok, now I have: `const dotEnvOptions = {
  path: '/.env',
  debug: true
};
dotenv.config(dotEnvOptions);`

How do I access the debug logs? They aren't in the browser console

Comment: I assigned dotenv.config(...) to dotenvSetup and logged it. Here is what it returned: `{error: TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
    at Object.config (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0…}
error: TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function at Object.config (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:6039:27) at Module../src/App.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:177:66) at __webpack_require__ `